# How to Create a PySpark UDF that Iterates through a column of arrays:

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

Beginner PySpark Question Here. **How do I create a udf that iterates through an array of strings within a column**

I have a dataframe of ~6M rows where I have extracted elements into seperate columns. Here is a sample:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
d = [{'1-ID': 'Alice', '2-Full_Classification': ["H02J 1/08 20060101AFI20151217BHEP", "B63H 21/17 20060101ALI20151217BHEP", 'B65D 39/12 20060101A I20051008RMEP'], '3-Section': ['H', 'B', 'B'],  '4-Class': ['02', '63', '65'], '5-SubClass': ['J', 'H', 'D']}]
schema = StructType([
    StructField("ID", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Full_Classification", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("Section", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("Class", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
    StructField("SubClass", ArrayType(StringType()), True)
    ])
df = spark.createDataFrame(d)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=100)
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- 1-ID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 2-Full_Classification: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 3-Section: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 4-Class: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- 5-SubClass: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
| 1-ID|                                                                               2-Full_Classification|3-Section|     4-Class|5-SubClass|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
|Alice|[H02J 1/08 20060101AFI20151217BHEP, B63H 21/17 20060101ALI20151217BHEP, B65D 39/12 20060101A I200...|[H, B, B]|[02, 63, 65]| [J, H, D]|
+-----+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+------------+----------+
```

I want to create a udf to calculate an 'agreement' score of each of the extracted lists/arrays like so:

```
List1 = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'] #agreement score would be 100%
List2 = ['12', '12', '12', '13', '13', '13'] #agreement score would be 50%
List3 = ['C', 'D', 'E'] #agreement score would be 0%
```

EDIT: Desired Output in This Case:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
| 1-ID|2-Full_Classification|3-Section|     4-Class|5-SubClass|Class-Score|Section-Score|SubClass-Score|
+-----+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
|Alice| [H02J 1/08 200601...|[H, B, B]|[02, 63, 65]| [J, H, D]|        0.0|         0.33|           0.0|
+-----+---------------------+---------+------------+----------+-----------+-------------+--------------+
```

Here is my udf:

```
def agreement(col):
    unique_items = set(list(col))
    unique_items_count = len(unique_items)
    if  unique_items_count == 1:
        agreement = 1.0
    elif  unique_items_count == len(list(col)):
        agreement =  0.0
    else:
        agreement = (1.0 - (unique_items_count / len(list(col)))
    return agreement
agreement_udf = udf(agreement)
df = df.withColumn('Section_Score', agreement_udf('3-Section'))
df.show()
```

However, when I execute this code, I am hit with the following error messages (the first one is for my full 6M row DF, the last is for the example df above):

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

OR

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

OR

> TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()

I am confused because each column contains an array of strings which should be iterable. Any advice super appreciate

Comment: Please clarify exactly what your agreement score should be for the single row you show in your example (preferably, add a couple of more rows along with the expected results); also, you don't show the definition of `agreement_udf`.

Comment: Good catch! Both have been added in the recent edit.

Comment: Still unclear how from `Section`, `Class`, `SubClass` you end up with the shown respective scores

Comment: The 'agreement score' for each field is based on how much each element in the respective array 'agrees' with each other. For example, 'Section-Score' is based on 'Section' array of ['H', 'B', 'B']. Per the udf, `score = (1 - (unique_values_count / all_array_values_count)) = 1 - 2/3 = 0.33.` The 'Class' array has 3 distinct values -['02', '63', '65']. None of these three values are the same (none of them agree with each other) so the score would be 0.0 ->  `elif  unique_items_count == len(list(col)): agreement =  0.0`